# Spotfire calculate the difference of values in a single column based on date for each group

Tags: calculated-columns, ranking, spotfire

I have a requirement of calculating the difference in Spotfire for values in a single column based on the occurrence.

the data looks like

| ID | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 07/01/2021 |
| 1 | 8 | 09/01/2021 |
| 1 | 10 | 10/01/2021 |
| 1 | 15 | 11/01/2021 |
| 1 | 6 | 12/01/2021 |
| 1 | 3 | 15/01/2021 |
| 2 | 10 | 07/01/2021 |
| 2 | 11 | 08/01/2021 |
| 2 | 12 | 09/01/2021 |

the expected output is

| ID | Value | Date | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 07/01/2021 | True |
| 1 | 8 | 09/01/2021 |  |
| 1 | 10 | 10/01/2021 |  |
| 1 | 15 | 11/01/2021 |  |
| 1 | 6 | 12/01/2021 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 15/01/2021 |  |
| 2 | 10 | 07/01/2021 | False |
| 2 | 11 | 08/01/2021 |  |
| 2 | 12 | 09/01/2021 |  |

the logic is

we need to find the flag by comparing the value of first received and latest received for each id.

for id 1 first received value is 7

for id 1 latest received value is 3

is 7>3 True .

for easy understanding i had sorted the id column.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can do this in two step:

First step :

```
Concatenate(String([Value])) OVER ([ID])
```

Will say you name this column : test

Which will give you (7,8,10,15,6,3)

Second step :

```
Integer(left([test],1)) > Integer(right([test],1))
```

| ID | Value | Date | test | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 07/01/2021 | 7, 8, 10, 15, 6, 3 | True |
| 1 | 8 | 09/01/2021 | 7, 8, 10, 15, 6, 3 | True |
| 1 | 10 | 10/01/2021 | 7, 8, 10, 15, 6, 3 | True |
| 1 | 15 | 11/01/2021 | 7, 8, 10, 15, 6, 3 | True |
| 1 | 6 | 12/01/2021 | 7, 8, 10, 15, 6, 3 | True |
| 1 | 3 | 15/01/2021 | 7, 8, 10, 15, 6, 3 | True |
| 2 | 10 | 07/01/2021 | 10, 11, 12 | False |
| 2 | 11 | 08/01/2021 | 10, 11, 12 | False |
| 2 | 12 | 09/01/2021 | 10, 11, 12 | False |

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion, the id column is not sorted by default, we can concatenate after sorting by date, can you please include that as well
Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry for answering this late I'm not sure that I have completely understand your problem but you can try this with date if the ID is the same :`Max(Concatenate(String([Value])) OVER (Intersect([ID],All([Date])))) OVER (Intersect([ID],All([Date])))`

Comment: Hi, we need to sort by date received and then concatenate